# my method returns an address at the link of a value

Tags: python, object

This is an exercise that is not part of the training on the site, I do not understand why when I want to display the return value of the energy method of my satellite class, I receive an address on the console.

```
Zoe satellite speed = 40.0m / s.
<bound method Satellite.energie of <__ main __. Satellite object at 0x01A5E610 >>
Zoe satellite speed = 70.0m / s.
<bound method Satellite.energie of <__ main __. Satellite object at 0x01A5E610 >>
```

This is my code:

```
class Satellite (object):
    "" "Satellite for instantiating objects simulating satellites
artificial launched into space, around the earth. "" "

    def __init __ (self, name, mass = 100, speed = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.mass = mass
        speed choke = speed

    def impulse (self, force, duration):
        "" "will vary the speed of the satellite." ""

        speed self = speed self + (force * duration) / mass self

    def energy (self):
        "" "will refer to the program calling the kinetic energy value of the satellite" ""
        return_val = self.mass * self.speed ** 2/2
        return return_val

    def display_speed (self):
        "" "will display the name of the satellite and its current speed." ""
        print ("satellite speed {0} = {1} m / s.". format (self.name, self.speed))


s1 = Satellite ('Zoe', mass = 250, speed = 10)
s1.pulse (500, 15)
s1.display_speed ()
print (s1.energy)
s1.pulse (500, 15)
s1.display_speed ()
print (s1.energy)
```

Comment: You need to call/invoke the method, like `s1.energy()`.

Comment: There are so many issues with the code you post. It would never run and produce the result you show. Please post your **actual** code, although some answers already point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `energy` method is wrong, and it should have given a syntax error:

```
def energy (self):
    "" "will refer to the program calling the kinetic energy value of the satellite" ""
    return_val = self.mass * self.speed ** 2/2
    return return_val
```

Not to mention, you need to invoke the `energy` method as well:

```
s1.pulse (500, 15)
s1.display_speed ()
print(s1.energy())
s1.pulse (500, 15)
s1.display_speed ()
print(s1.energy())
```

You are trying to overwrite the `return` statement and use it as a variable, which is just WRONG. There are other mistypings/issues in your code as well, but this one definitely seems to be main issue.

Comment: Thank you I have modified the code but it still returns an address

Comment: The code you have posted doesn’t even run, are you sure you have posted the correct code?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling the function `Satellite.energy()`, you're trying to access the property `Satellite.energy` - if you change it to `print(s1.energy())`, it should display correctly!

As a note, some of your code has been formatted wrong here so it doesn't run - this works for me:

```py
class Satellite (object):
    "" "Satellite for instantiating objects simulating satellites artificial launched into space, around the earth. "" "

    def __init__ (self, name, mass = 100, speed = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.mass = mass
        self.speed = speed

    def impulse (self, force, duration):
        "" "will vary the speed of the satellite." ""

        return self.speed + (force * duration) / self.mass

    def energy (self):
        "" "will refer to the program calling the kinetic energy value of the satellite" ""
        return self.mass * self.speed ** 2/2

    def display_speed (self):
        "" "will display the name of the satellite and its current speed." ""
        print ("satellite speed {0} = {1} m / s.". format (self.name, self.speed))


s1 = Satellite ('Zoe', mass = 250, speed = 10)
s1.impulse (500, 15)
s1.display_speed ()
print (s1.energy())
s1.impulse (500, 15)
s1.display_speed ()
print (s1.energy())
```